# why is it not possible to use if let syntax in an initializer to call a failable initializer from a subclass’s nonfailable initializer? [swift]

Tags: swift, initialization

According to Apple, "You can use forced unwrapping in an initializer to call a failable initializer from the superclass as part of the implementation of a subclass’s nonfailable initializer." The code they provided is shown below:

```
class Document {
var name: String?
// this initializer creates a document with a nil name value
init() {}
// this initializer creates a document with a nonempty name value
init?(name: String) {
    if name.isEmpty { return nil }
    self.name = name
}
}
class UntitledDocument: Document {
override init() {
    super.init(name: "[Untitled]")!
}
}
```

I replaced the subclass with the following code but the if let syntax didn't work. My understanding of the if let syntax is the provision of a safer tool, so why doesn't it work here?

```
class UntitledDocument: Document {
override init() {
    if let xx = super.init(name: "[Untitled]") {
        xx
    }

}
}
```

Comment: What should the subclass init method do if super.init(...)  fails?

Comment: it's possible to add an else statement. I understand that the conveniency of the ! in this case, but i'm just wondering...

Answer (score 0):

So, interestingly enough, when I tried using a nil coalescing operator (??) this is the error/warning I get:

[image: swift error]

It looks like the swift compiler doesn't treat failable initializers the same as optionals, so "if let" usages won't work with them.